# IntelliJ IDEA scala import error

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ IDEA 13 CE with Scala plugin 0.38.441. On MacOS 10.10.

but I got this error
[image]

how to resolve it. thanks!

Comment: What is your module type? Is this class in your classpath?

Comment: yes. scala library is in the project's External Libraries.

Comment: What version of scala-library?

Comment: scala library version is 2.11.1

Comment: Does everything compile correctly with SBT? How are you importing, via sbt-idea or directly from File -> Import... ?

Comment: from File -> Import. everything compile and run correctly with SBT.  @MarioCamou

Comment: same error via sbt-idea